# Unity: Adding impulse to a ball from a certain position

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics

I'm making a 3d pool game and I stuck with this problem.
I can't find the needed function to add an impulse to a ball which will make the ball to spin.
In other words, how to set the AIM point from where I want to add the impulse?

[image]

If I use AddForce or AddTorque, it seems that it calculates it from the Center of the Ball.
But how to specify the aim point (Left english, Right english, etc...)?
And how to route the ball to the camera direction after a cue hit the ball?

Answer (score 0):

At first look I think you should check [Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition.html). You should calculate the aim points somehow in world coordinates also.

I am relatively new on Unity but the main idea came to my mind first rotate the cue vector by y axis by a small amount angle, then calculate the hit point for each regions by casting physics ray then finally apply impulse by using Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition. I tried to write a sample code:

```
public class SphereController : MonoBehaviour {

private Vector3 cueStartPoint;

void Start () {

    cueStartPoint = new Vector3(0, 0.5f, -13f);

}

void Update () {

    //direction from cue to center
    var direction = transform.position - cueStartPoint;

    //rotate cue to aim right english
    var angleForRightEnglish = 5f;
    var directionForRight = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angleForRightEnglish, Vector3.up) * direction;
    Debug.DrawRay(cueStartPoint, directionForRight, Color.red, 10f);

    //rotate cue to aim right english
    var angleForLeftEnglish = -5f;
    var directionForLeft = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angleForLeftEnglish, Vector3.up) * direction;
    Debug.DrawRay(cueStartPoint, directionForLeft, Color.blue, 10f);

    //try a sample hit from right
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
        var forceMagnitude = 1f;
        var hitForce = forceMagnitude * directionForRight.normalized;

        //calculate right hit point on sphere surface
        RaycastHit hitInfo;
        if (Physics.Raycast(cueStartPoint, directionForRight, out hitInfo)) {
            var rightHitPoint = hitInfo.point;
            gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForceAtPosition(hitForce, rightHitPoint, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }

    }

    //try a sample hit from left
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
        var forceMagnitude = 1f;
        var hitForce = forceMagnitude * directionForLeft.normalized;

        //calculate left hit point on sphere surface
        RaycastHit hitInfo;
        if (Physics.Raycast(cueStartPoint, directionForLeft, out hitInfo)) {
            var leftHitPoint = hitInfo.point;
            gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForceAtPosition(hitForce, leftHitPoint, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }

    }

}

}
```

this script should be added to ball as component of course, hope this helps.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: I updated my answer, if anything I get wrong please tell me

Comment: That will not work. Yes the ball will get a little spin (way less than what it should) however the off center hit will send the ball in the wrong direction. The ball / cue contact is imperfect elastic  (the tip grabs and throws the ball) Best to hit the ball dead center, use `ball.AddTorque(x, y, z, ForceMode.Force);` to add  spin. Remember it's a 80kg human striking a 0.17kg ball at good speed applied over about 1ms and contact area of about 15mm squared, A perfect elastic (rigidbody) collision will send that ball off at the speed of a bullet